How can I make \\u be \u in generated JSON?
public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
    final ObjectMapper jackson = new ObjectMapper();
    
    final ObjectNode objectNode = jackson.createObjectNode();
    String text = "Simplified Chinese 简体中文";
    
    final String escapedInUnicodeText = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(text);
    System.out.println(escapedInUnicodeText);
    //output is: Simplified Chinese \u7B80\u4F53\u4E2D\u6587
    
    objectNode.put("text", escapedInUnicodeText);
    System.out.println(jackson.writeValueAsString(objectNode));
    //output is  {"text":"Simplified Chinese \\u7B80\\u4F53\\u4E2D\\u6587"}
}

Result of System.out.println(escapedInUnicodeText); is Simplified Chinese \u7B80\u4F53\u4E2D\u6587
Result of System.out.println(jackson.writeValueAsString(objectNode)); is {"text":"Simplified Chinese \\u7B80\\u4F53\\u4E2D\\u6587"}.
Regarding the 2nd result, the generated JSON, how can I make \\u be \u?

Just put text into the objectNode instead of escaping on your own. Jackson will escape it, if necessary and/or configured like that or put it directly. Why do you care if it's sent as \uabcd or actual UTF-8 bytes? Both are fine for any valid (and equivalent) JSON reading library.

What happens if you skip the escapeJava step?

You can use the JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII feature, but also ensure that your string is not double-escaped during the serialization process.
To achieve this, you can configure Jackson to not escape Unicode characters when serializing. This involves using the Jackson ObjectMapper and customizing its serialization settings.
Here's how I would do this:
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.node.ObjectNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonGenerator;

public class UnicodeExample {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        // Create ObjectMapper with custom settings
        ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();

        // Disable the default escaping for non-ASCII characters
        mapper.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII, false);

        // Example text with Unicode escapes
        String escapedInUnicodeText = "Simplified Chinese \u7B80\u4F53\u4E2D\u6587";
        
        // Create an ObjectNode and add the text
        ObjectNode objectNode = mapper.createObjectNode();
        objectNode.put("text", escapedInUnicodeText);
        
        // Serialize the object to JSON
        String jsonString = mapper.writeValueAsString(objectNode);

        // Output the result
        System.out.println(jsonString);
    }
}


Thank you @Thomas Boje / @Joachim Sauer,
    @Override
    public void run(String... args) throws Exception {
        final ObjectMapper jackson = new ObjectMapper();
        
        final ObjectNode objectNode = jackson.createObjectNode();
        String text = "Simplified Chinese 简体中文";

        // Enable escaping for non-ASCII characters, which is disabled by default
        jackson.configure(JsonGenerator.Feature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII, true);
        
        //no need to escape by ourselves, jackson will handle it after we enable the ESCAPE_NON_ASCII feature.
        //final String escapedInUnicodeText = StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava(text);
        //System.out.println(escapedInUnicodeText);
        //output is: Simplified Chinese \u7B80\u4F53\u4E2D\u6587
        
        objectNode.put("text", text);
        System.out.println(jackson.writeValueAsString(objectNode));
        //output is  {"text":"Simplified Chinese \u7B80\u4F53\u4E2D\u6587"}
    }

